# Computation and Sums Problem

Tags: summation, computational-mathematics

Compute $\sum_{k = 1}^{1000} ((1000 - k) \text{ div } 100)$.

I need help with this one. I tried to simplify it into two summations but got lost.

Comment: Gauss knew how to do this during elementary school...

Comment: But Gauss is intelligent unlike me.

Comment: By $a$ div $b$ do you mean $\lfloor \frac{a}{b}\rfloor$?

Comment: @rogerl Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, which values of $k$ give a quotient of zero? How many such values are there? How about a quotient of 1? Generalize.

Comment: did my answer answer your question? You have not commented nor accepted, so I don't know if you are still confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information in the comments, I will assume $∑^{1000}_{k=1}((1000−k) div 100)= ∑^{1000}_{k=1}\lfloor {(1000−k)/100}\rfloor$ .

Then, with $100\ge k \ge 1$ , the $k$th term of the sum equals $9$. Then the sum equals $100 *9=900$.
Doing this for other values of $k$ we get to the answer $∑^{1000}_{k=1}((1000−k) div 100)$= $100*\frac {9*10}{2}= 4500$